# ERStudio issue for reverse engineering a SQL Server 2019 in a docker Ubuntu container?

Tags: database, docker, data-modeling

SSMS and Azure Data Studio have no problem connect to the container on port 12001(:1433).

The issue extends to any relational database that is containerized in a docker Unbuntu (Linux) container.

Additional, can the recommendation be extended to resolve connections to any NOSQL databases supported be ERStudio such as MongoDB?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It started to work when I reinstalled Docker.  Although, it had worked with SSMS and Azure Data Studio.